I need a return D if value on 3 columns (A,B,C) match the reference table 3 column
I need to know how many sessions the insurance allows depending on demographics.
I have column A (insurance 1 or insurance 2), Column B (adult or minor), and column 3 (level of care 1 or 2). Depending on which 3 values in Columns A, B, and C, column D will have a different number of allowed sessions. This is the simple explanation for the example, in my real-life situation, there are 5 insurances and 5 levels.
COLUMN A  / COLUMN B/ COLUMN C / COLUMN D
INSURANCE 1 / MINOR / LEVEL 1 / 10 SESSIONS
INSURANCE 1 / MINOR / LEVEL 2 / 20 SESSIONS
INSURANCE 1 / ADULT / LEVEL 1 / 5 SESSIONS
INSURANCE 1 / ADULT / LEVEL 2 / 10 SESSIONS
INSURANCE 2 / MINOR / LEVEL 1 / 15 SESSIONS
INSURANCE 2 / MINOR / LEVEL 2 / 30 SESSIONS
INSURANCE 2 / ADULT / LEVEL 1 / 10 SESSIONS
INSURANCE 2 / ADULT / LEVEL 2 / 20 SESSIONS
I tried the IF, THEN type of formulas, but I didn't quite get the exact order of the elements of the formula.

You can use the FILTER function.
In the formula below, I Name'd the table Sessions and used Named Ranges for the three variables.
I would also suggest you use Data Validation list dropdowns for the named variables to avoid the possibility of misspellings.
=IFERROR(
    FILTER(
        Sessions[COLUMN D],
        (Sessions[COLUMN A] = Company) *
            (Sessions[COLUMN B] = Age) *
            (Sessions[COLUMN C] = Level)
    ),
    ""
)


If you have an older version of Excel which lacks the FILTER function, you can use:
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        Sessions[COLUMN D],
        MATCH(
            1,
            (Sessions[COLUMN A] = Company) *
                (Sessions[COLUMN B] = Age) *
                (Sessions[COLUMN C] = Level),
            0
        )
    ),
    ""
)


Here is another way you could try, provided you are using MS365 and while writing the following formula have enabled the Office Insiders:


• Formula used in cell D3
=FILTER(Demotbl[[ COLUMN D ]],
 BYROW(N(A3:C3=Demotbl[[COLUMN A ]:[ COLUMN C ]]),SUM)=3,"")


Or, Using MMULT() if you don't have access to BYROW() without LAMBDA() construct aka ETA LAMBDA
=FILTER(Demotbl[[ COLUMN D ]],
 MMULT(N(A3:C3=Demotbl[[COLUMN A ]:[ COLUMN C ]]),{1;1;1})=3,"")



To be honest, if you don't really need the word SESSIONS to appear, you can use SUMIFS if your SESSIONS column values are just numeric:

=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$9;$A$2:$A$9;G9;$B$2:$B$9;$H$9;$C$2:$C$9;I9)

Then, you can add custom format like I did in cell J13 just using format = Standar "Sessions", but to be honest, I think it's not necessary.
